# Rails 5 - embed a register interest form in root page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, heroku

I've made a scaffold in my Rails app called Leads. The table has 1 attribute, being :email.

My objective is to render the form input field in the homepage.

I have a HomeController, to which I've added this "new" method.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @lead = Lead.new
  end

end
```

In the home/index view, I have:

```
        <%= render 'leads/form', lead: @lead %>
```

In the form partial I have:

```
    <%= simple_form_for Lead.new do |f| %>

      <%= f.input :email, :label => false, :placeholder => "your email address", input_html: { class: 'cform'  }   %>


    <span style="float:right"><%= f.button :submit, 'Go', class: 'cformbutton' %></span>

<% end %>
```

I'm trying to follow the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177803/embed-a-rails-form-partial-into-another-page) to get the form input field to show in the home index.

I cant find a way to make it work.

It works fine in the development environment but then when I push to heroku, I get an error that says:

```
FATAL -- : [a6e63810-1660-4e83-86d9-bfd6ae54b344] ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "leads" does not exist
2017-03-01T21:19:11.541780+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-01T21:19:11.541735 #4] FATAL -- : [a6e63810-1660-4e83-86d9-bfd6ae54b344]   
2017-03-01T21:19:11.541824+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"leads"'::regclass
```

My lead.rb has no associations on it. I don't understand why there need to be any associations.

Can anyone see what I need to do in order to get this form to work in the production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "leads" does not exist` clearly says that your `leads` table does not exists. That's because you most likely forgot to run migrations on Heroku.

To fix it run this command `heroku run rake db:migrate --app your_application_name`. Or drop `--app` part if you have only one application.

Please be aware that Heroku does not automatically run your migrations when you deploy new code. You need to do it manually every time you add new migrations. If you want to automate this, there are many options. I think the easiest will be to add this buildpack `https://github.com/gunpowderlabs/buildpack-ruby-rake-deploy-tasks`.

Here are the steps if you want to go with this options:

```
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/gunpowderlabs/buildpack-ruby-rake-deploy-tasks --app your_application_name
heroku config:set DEPLOY_TASKS='db:migrate' --app your_application_name
```